# NVIDIA issues in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia

When I install Ubuntu 20.04 on my Asus X71SL laptop with the **NVIDIA GeForce 9300M GS** graphics card the screen goes black. I have tried to do many things that are said about NVIDIA cards but none of them works for me. Could you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Would you share what you've done so far? At least I'd expect you to install the propriety nvidia drivers... Please explain how you installed the drivers, if you did.

Answer (score 1):

Your GPU is not supported by the newest proprietary drivers - the newest series that supports it is 340, according to https://www.geforce.com/drivers (don't try to install your driver from there - it'll go wrong). The 340 series Nvidia driver is not compatible with the Xorg 1.20 server, so you'll have to use Nouveau.

Could you please clarify when exactly does your screen go black? Is it after booting the installation USB, or after finishing the installation and rebooting?

Answer (score 0):

the post is a bit dated but if it can help some

I'm not an English speaker, so sorry for the translation

if the computer blocks during installation, go to the bios, option security, I / O Interface Security, Nex Card Interface, set the parameter to "LOCKED"

Can solve the problem

If you have successfully installed the system but nothing is displayed then:

When the Grub menu is displayed select the line "advanced option of the kernel to start", type enter, select the kernel to start, without typing enter and edit the command line with the "e" key

Find the line that contains the kernel version to boot example:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-xxxxxx root=UUID=2630b494-8ca2-4672-bae9-fa29b58ab472 ro  quiet initrd  /boot/initrd.img-xxxxx
```

Add the parameter:

```
pci=nomsi
```

after the parameters:quiet splash"

Normally this will run the "new" free driver and start the graphics display.

it can happen even with this parameter that from time to time the graphic display starts up and this hangs before logging in, shutting down the computer and restarting

If it doesn't work you can replace the indicated parameter by this one:

```
nomodeset
```

which will have the effect of deactivating the "nouveau" driver, a base driver will be used , it can help, but you will not benefit from the graphics acceleration

If it works, you will have to add the parameter to the grub configuration file so that it is permanent.

just add them to the variable:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX ou GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
```

in the /etc/default/grub file and run in the terminal

```
update-grub
```

to rebuild /boot/grub/grub.cfg

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT : contains parameters to pass to all Linux menu entries.

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX : contains parameters to pass to normal Linux menu entries but not to "recovery mode" entries.

Bye;)