# Nvidia driver on Kubuntu 20.04 does not load X or Steam

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, 20.04

I have installed kubuntu 20.04 and when I tried to install nvidia drivers X does not start. The ubuntu-drivers devices shows this:

```
filho@filho:~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000DE9sv00001043sd000010ACbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF108M [GeForce GT 620M/630M/635M/640M LE]
manual_install: True
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

I have tried `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and also `apt-get install nvidia-driver-390`. The result is the one I described above, X does not start. I have to start an older kernel version and purge nvidia.

I also have tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1266722/935425) solution, but it did not work

## Edit

I have managed to get X running after installing the nvidia driver. Before rebooting I ran `nvidia-settings` and choose the option "NVIDIA On-Demand" than rebooted. But when I tried to run Steam I got a window message saying "OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display".

Please help me.

Comment: Did you try removing  nvidia-driver-450 ..

Comment: Not specifically that, but it was never installed, and I've run `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` many times as I tried and retried solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `sudo prime-select nvidia` and rebooting (after installing the drivers)?

Also, after doing so, check the tab *Additional Drivers* in *Software & Updates* settings to see if the driver actually shows up as installed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not have tried that before, but when I did `sudo prime-select nvidia` returned that it was already selected and in the settings the driver was installed and selected. In any way I rebooted the computer and the same happened.

Comment: About your edit: AFAIK, the version 390 of the driver does not support on-demand. You were able to get X running because the integrated GPU was being used. IIRC, using `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` may remove more files than needed (had this problem before). If possible, I back up up your files and reinstall Ubuntu from scratch. Don't install the proprietary drivers during the OS installation. After it completes, update/upgrade packages (reboot if necessary). THEN, install the recommended driver (390) from _Software & Updates_. Finally, `sudo prime-select nvidia` and REBOOT (mandatory).

Comment: Summing up: 1- _On-Demand_ isn't available in 390; 2- `sudo prime-select` requires a reboot to apply changes (at least it does on Ubuntu 20.04); 3- `purge` and `remove` combined with wildcards such as `*` may lead to unpredictable results (in my case, reinstalling the OS was easier than fixing what I broke); 4- the error "OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display" on Steam (and other graphical applications) indicates that the Nvidia GPU ins't selected and working